# Reactive Expressions in Shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I'm new to Shiny and R but have some programming experience. My end goal is to develop an online Multiple Choice Questionnaire and perform some statistical analysis.

I'm currently trying to create an MCQ and in order to better understand and learn how to do it using R and Shiny I'm using J Bryers code ([link to code](https://gist.github.com/jbryer/e17c5587a43188258ee5)) as a basis for creating both ui.R and server.R scripts (as opposed to app.R). I originally came across this framework at [r-bloggers.com](http://www.r-bloggers.com/conducting-assessments-and-surveys-with-shiny/). I've included the code I'm working on which is throwing me an error. If anyone has time to reply I'd appreciate any help/advice on getting it up an running.

The error is

> Warning: Error in .getReactiveEnvironment()$currentContext: Operation not allowed without an active reactive context. (You tried to do something that can only be done from inside a reactive expression or observer.) Stack trace (innermost first): 45: .getReactiveEnvironment()$currentContext 44: .subset2(x, "impl")$get 43: $.reactivevalues 42: $ 41: paste 40: server [D:\MyShinyApps\MCQ 2/server.R#150] 1: runApp

The items.csv file can be found at the first link above.

Thanks

ui.R

```
################################################################################
#
# Create user interface
#
################################################################################

library(shiny) # load the shiny package
library(ggplot2)

# define the UI for the shiny application
shinyUI(
 ## if(!exists("SHOW_MCQ")) {
 ##   fluidPage(width = 12)
 ## } else {
  fluidPage(
    # application title

    titlePanel("Maths Multiple Choice Questions"),
        sidebarLayout(
      sidebarPanel(
        h4("Multiple Choice Quiz"),
        h5("Created by: Edmund Nevin"),
        h5("Developed Using: Shiny R"),
        p('Use the button below to start the assessment'),
        uiOutput("ui"),
        hr()
      ), # end of sidebarPanel()

      mainPanel(
        h3("MCQ Results"),
        textOutput("maths.results")



      ) # end of mainPanel()
    ) # end of sidebarlayout()
  ) # end of fluidPage()
  ##}
) # end of shinyUI()
```

server.R

```
################################################################################
#
# Instructiuons that uses input provided by the user
#
################################################################################

library(shiny) # load the shiny package
library(ggplot2)

# read the maths questions (i.e. item stems) from file
maths.items <- read.csv("items.csv", stringsAsFactors = FALSE) # create data frame

# create a vector with the item stems
maths.stems <- list() # build a list of questions

shinyServer(

  function(input, output) {

    # assign variables
    item.stems = maths.items$Stem # create a character vector with item stems
    item.choices = maths.items[,c(4:8)] # create a data frame with item answers
    itemsPerPage = 1 # set number of items per page
    totalPages <- ceiling(length(item.stems) / itemsPerPage) # calculate total pages

    # define reactive values
    ASSESSMENT <- reactiveValues(
      currentPage = 1,
      responses = rep(as.integer(NA), length(item.stems))
    )


    # UI elements
    start.label = "Start the Test" # button label
    start.name = "Start Button" # start button
    cancel.name = "Cancel Button" # cancel button
    page.name = "Page"

    # error check
    stopifnot(length(item.stems) == nrow(item.choices))

    # allow multiple assessments to be run by putting an object in the 
    # calling environment by putting "SHOW_MCQ" object in the calling
    # environment
    if(!exists("SHOW_MCQ", envir = parent.env(environment()))) {
      assign("SHOW_MCQ", value = reactiveValues(show = FALSE, assessment = NULL,
                                                unique = format(Sys.time(), '%Y%m%d%H%M%S')),
             envir = parent.env(environment())
      ) # end of assign()
    } # end of if statement


    # start button
    output$start <- renderUI({
      observe({
        if(!is.null(input[[paste0(start.name, SHOW_MCQ$unique)]])) {
          if(input[[paste0(start.name, SHOW_MCQ$unique) == 1]]) {
            SHOW_MCQ$show <- TRUE
            SHOW_MCQ$assessment <- ui.name
          } # end inner if statement
        } # end outer if statement

      }) # end observe()

      actionButton(paste0(start.name, SHOW_MCQ$unique), start.label)

    }) # end renderUI()

    # cancel button
    output$cancel <- renderUI({
      observe({
        if(!is.null(input[[paste0(cancel.name, SHOW_MCQ$unique)]])) {
          if(input[[paste0(cancel.name, SHOW_MCQ$unique)]] == 1) {
            SHOW_MCQ$show <- FALSE
            SHOW_MCQ$assessment <- NULL
            SHOW_MCQ$unique <- format(Sys.time(), "%Y%m%d%H%M%S")
            ASSESSMENT$currentPage <- 1
            ASSESSMENT$responses <- rep(as.integer(NA), length(item.stems))
          } #end of inner if statement
        } # end of outer if statement

      }) # end observe()

      actionButton(paste0(cancel.name, SHOW_MCQ$unique, "Cancel" ))

    }) # end renderUI


    # radio buttons

    output$ui <- renderUI({
      buttons <- list() # build a list of buttons

      for(i in seq_len(length(item.stems))) {
        choices <- character() # build a character vector of choices
        for(j in 1:ncol(item.choices)) { # loop through columns
          if(!is.na(item.choices[i,j])) {
            choices[(j)] <- names(item.choices)[j] # populate choices vector
            names(choices)[j] <- HTML(item.choices[i,j]) # mark the given text as HTML
            } # end of if statement
          } # end of inner for statement

        button.label <- "" # clear the button label

        if(is.character(item.stems)) {
          button.label <- HTML(item.stems[i])
        } else {
          button.label <- item.stems[[i]]
        }

        buttons[[i]] <- radioButtons(inputId = paste0(i, SHOW_MCQ$unique),
                                          label = button.label,
                                          choices = choices,
                                          inline = FALSE,
                                          selected = character(),
                                          width = "100%")  
      } # end of outer for statement

      startPos <- ((ASSESSMENT$currentPage - 1) * itemsPerPage) + 1
      pos <- seq(startPos, min((startPos + itemsPerPage - 1), length(buttons)))

      observe({
        if(SHOW_MCQ$show &
          !is.null(input[[paste0(save.name, SHOW_MCQ$unique)]])
        ) {
          if(input[[paste0(save.name, SHOW_MCQ$unique)]] == 1) {
            results <- character(length(item.stems)) # build a character vector for results
            for(i in seq_len(length(buttons))) {
              ans <- input[[paste0(name, i, SHOW_MCQ$unique)]] 
              results[i] <- ifelse(is.null(ans, NA, ans))
              } #end of for statement

            #callback(results) # do callback

            # reset for another assessment
            SHOW_MCQ$show <- FALSE
            SHOW_MCQ$assessment <- NULL
            SHOW_MCQ$unique <- format(Sys.time(), "%Y%m%d%H%M%S")
            ASSESSMENT$currentPage <- 1
            ASSESSMENT$responses <- rep(as.integer(NA), length(item.stems))
            } # end of inner if statement
          } # end of inner if statement
        }) # end of observe()
      }) # end of renderUI()

    # increment the page
    nextButtonName <- paste("Page", ASSESSMENT$current$Page, SHOW_MCQ$unique)

    if(!is.null(input[[nextButtonName]])) {
      if(input[[nextButtonName]] == 1) {
        for(i in seq(((ASSESSMENT$currentPage - 1) * itemsPerPage) + 1,
                      Assessment$currentPAGE * itemsPerPage, by = 1)) {
          ans <- input[[paste0(i, SHOW_MCQ$unique)]]
          ASSESSMENT$currentPage <- ASSESSMENT$currentPage + 1
          nextButtonName <- paste0(page.name, ASSESSMENT$currentPage)
          } # end of for statement
        } # end of inner if statement
      } # end of outer if statement


    # Next or Done button
    if(ASSESSMENT$currentPage == totalPages) {
      nextButton <- ActionButton(paste0("Save", SHOW_MCQ$unique), "Done")
    } else {
      nextButton <- actionButton(nextButtonName, "Next")
    }

    mainPanel(width = 12,
              br(),
              buttons[pos],
              br(),
              fluidRow(
                column(width = 2, uiOutput(cancel.name)),
                column(width = 8, p(paste0("Page ", ASSESSMENT$currentPage, " of ", totalPages)),
                       align = "center"),
                column(width = 2, nextButton)
                )
              )

    # save the most recent assessment results to display
    mcq.results <- reactiveValues(maths = logical())


    # function called when assessment is completed
    saveResults <- function(results) {
      mcq.results$maths <- results == maths.items$Answer
    } # end of function 'saveResults'


    # provide some feedback to test taker
    output$maths.results <- renderText({
      txt <- ""
      if(length(mcq.results$maths) > 0) {
        txtmsg <- paste0("You got ", sum(mcq.results$math, na.rm = True,
                                      " of ", length(mcq.results$math), " items correct."))
      } else {
        txtmsg <- "No results found. Please complete the MCQ." 
      }
      return(txtmsg)
      }) # end of feedback message


    } # end of function
  ) # end of shinyServer()
```

Comment: What specifically is the error you are getting?

Comment: Hi Carl. I'm getting the following.

Comment: Warning: Error in .getReactiveEnvironment()$currentContext: Operation not allowed without an active reactive context. (You tried to do something that can only be done from inside a reactive expression or observer.)
Stack trace (innermost first):
    45: .getReactiveEnvironment()$currentContext
    44: .subset2(x, "impl")$get
    43: $.reactivevalues
    42: $
    41: paste
    40: server [D:\MyShinyApps\MCQ 2/server.R#150]
     1: runApp

Comment: It looks like the issue may be trying to use the reactiveValues stored in `ASSESSMENT` outside of a reactive function, e.g. : `nextButtonName <- paste("Page", ASSESSMENT$current$Page, SHOW_MCQ$unique)` does not (at quick glance) appear to be inside one of your reactive functions.